# Can compile with 2.11.2, but not 2.11.3

Tags: scala, sbt, assertion

build.sbt file:

```
name := "Bag"

version := "0.7.252"

scalaVersion := "2.11.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.1.3" % "test",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing" % "1.0.1",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.2"
)
```

The project compile properly with 2.11.2, but on 2.11.3 I get [this](http://pastebin.com/3dGmugzb).

Comment: So, uh, report it. http://www.scala-lang.org/contribute/bug-reporting-guide.html

Comment: You're using scalatest_2.10 with scalaVersion 2.11.

Comment: I edited build.sbt to use scalatest_2.11 and it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala 2.11.3 is not yet officially released, although as you have witnessed, the artifact was already pushed to Maven Central.

I think that version will be "pulled" because of a binary incompatibility bug introduced in collections. See [SI-8899](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8899) and [SI-8900](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8900). Stick to 2.11.2 until a new version (2.11.4?) will be announced.

I'm not sure I understand what is going on in your case, reading the pastbin, but I suggest you open another ticket unless it clearly stems from either of these two issues.

Comment: It's the assert in SI-8900, but it would be nice to know what triggered it.  There's not enough info in the link.

Answer (score 0):

[Scala 2.11.3 is not officially released and not recommend.](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.11.4#do_not_use_scala_2113) If you want to read the whole story see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/SSD9BNJaFbU/rACBkHrs2JEJ).
Scala 2.11.4 should be used instead.